# СentOS 6: установка и настройка

Tags: centos, lamp

Как в CentOS 6 правильно установить Apache, MySQL, PHP, Perl, FTP, Mail и сконфигурироватьэти службы вместе, предположительно для использования в качестве веб-сервера.

Comment: Для связки Apache, MySQL, PHP, Pear могу посоветовать LAMPP скачать [здесь](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html), там и инструкция по установке есть.

Comment: Спасибо,но необходима отдельная установка всех этих компонентов и конфигурирование воедино.Подобные "комбайны" не совсем то,на мой взгляд, в нихмного нестоль необходимого

Comment: Что значит комбайны? Там есть даже минимальная версия. Плюс включение/отключение любого плагина. Тем более, что уже все оптимизировано и работает:)

Answer (score 1):

Тематика вопроса очень широка, материала хватит на несколько статей для блога. Поэтому ссылки:

- [Установка Apache, MySQL, PHP на CenOS](http://easylinux.ru/node/289/).
- [Установка Perl](http://m0hn.blogspot.com/2011/01/perl-588-perl-5100-centos-linux.html)
- [Установка FTP](http://easylinux.ru/node/195/)
- [Установка Mail](http://worm.org.ua/2011/10/exim-centos/)